# If height param is not number - then log and set to default

Tags: javascript

I am creating a class with a constructor and instead of double handling, I thought I would use a one line conditional and if the class property is not set correctly then `console.log` out a message.

I want to know if there is a cleaner implementation for the following `height property` as at the moment I don't think readability is overly terrific.

This is <strike>*basically*</strike> what I have:

```js
class Example1 {
  constructor(height) {
    this.defaultHeight = 100;

    this.height = !isNaN(height) ? height : (() => {
      console.log("That was not a number >> " + height);
      return this.defaultHeight
    })();

  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
console.log("init example 1 w/ height of 0")
var example1 = new Example1(0);
console.log("example1.height is ", example1.height);
console.log("init example 2 w/ height of 'bob'")
var example2 = new Example1("bob");
console.log("example2.height is ", example2.height);
```

Comment: @Jamal Can you please confirm that `If height param is not number - then log and set to default.` would be a more appropriate title? I found "The norm is to summarize the goal of the code in the title. " a little vague in the help link.

Comment: That could work.

Comment: '*Basically?*' We don't like 'basically' or 'mostly' or 'sorta' or any other example or hypothetical code here, perhaps you should post a *concrete* example that is *likely to be used in-production* to avoid the potential for closure.

Comment: @EBrown Consider it done.

Comment: @Zze That's partially fine, I won't be one to close-vote it, but understand that reviews you get are **going** to be specific to that code. Good luck, and I hope you get solid reviews. :)

Answer (score 2):

I usually only use ternaries if I can keep my code clean and at the same time keep the ternary under 2-3 lines. That's just me, but I would make a few small changes to increase readability.

```
class Example1 {
  constructor(height) {
    this.defaultHeight = 100;

    this.height = typeof height === 'number' ? height : 
      (() => {
        console.log(height, 'is not a number');
        return this.defaultHeight;
      })();

  }
}
```